# Spring Boot Where is the dispatcher servlet located?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlets, web-container

I'm studying about spring boot and dispatcher servlet.

but I have no idea where is the exact location of dispatcher servlet.
I saw two pictures describe dispatcher servlet and web container, but they are different.

I've been looking for an answer for this one, but I can't seem to find a good answer.

**Q. Exact location of dispatcher servlet.**
first one, dispatcher servlet located in servlet container.
second one, dispatcher servlet located in spring container.
which one is right?

[located in servlet container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQzAL.png)

[located in spring container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajcli.png)

Answer (score 0):

DispatcherServlet class located in package "org.springframework.web.servlet" (spring-mvc.jar). Not in Tomcat container